# Aggregate works in mongo shell, but not in node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, nosql, aggregate

I'm trying to do something very simple in a GraphQL resolver: dumping data from one collection to another.

This works in the mongo shell
`db.srcColl.aggregate([{$out: "foobarbaz"}])`

This does not work in Node

```
db.collection("srcColl").aggregate([
    {$out: "foobarbaz"}
  ])
```

**No errors are being thrown**, it's just not doing anything.

I have a console log before and after it so I know it's being ran. I've tried doing it with async/await as well as with a callback.

Does anybody have any idea why this could be happening?

mongodb v3.5.5

UPDATE: I made a script and a screenshot to show the entire problem. You can see it does not work in node, but works in mongo.
[image]

Comment: Did you check whether you've got connected to correct DB, Check your collection string !

Comment: Yes. Connection string is correct because I can change the aggregate to a `find` and it works.

Comment: Try enabling database profiling and/or set slowms to 0 so that all queries get logged.  Then you can see exactly what is or isn't being run on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is based on the documentation for aggregation on the node mongodb driver website. 
[MongoDB NodeJS 3.6 driver documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/tutorials/aggregation/)

Note: You will not have any results returned since you used the $out operator in your pipeline. You can verify the aggregate is working correctly by commenting out the $out line.

```js
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'dbname';

// Create a new MongoClient
const client = new MongoClient(url);

// Use connect method to connect to the Server
client.connect(function (err, client) {
    assert.equal(null, err);
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");

    const db = client.db(dbName);

    simplePipeline(db, function () {
        client.close();
    });
});

function simplePipeline(db, callback) {
    const collection = db.collection('srcColl');
    collection.aggregate([
        //[{ '$match': { "borough": "Bronx" } },
        { '$out': 'foobazbar' },

    ],
        function (err, cursor) {
            assert.equal(err, null);

            cursor.toArray(function (err, documents) {
                console.log(documents)
                callback(documents);
            });
        }
    );
}
```

Source Collection:

```
> db.srcColl.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec82abbed4a7db1b6d414fc"), "name" : "tom" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ece58d6a61e6a47b8dd85cc"), "name" : "baz" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ece58d95630d9f3b9aef91e"), "name" : "foo" }
```

Destination Collection after running above code:

```
> db.foobazbar.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ec82abbed4a7db1b6d414fc"), "name" : "tom" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ece58d6a61e6a47b8dd85cc"), "name" : "baz" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ece58d95630d9f3b9aef91e"), "name" : "foo" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I've accepted dJackson's answer, but to sum up the problem, I was missing `toArray()`.

So instead of

```
db.collection("srcColl").aggregate([{$out: "foobarbaz"}])
```

I simply needed

```
db.collection("srcColl").aggregate([{$out: "foobarbaz"}]).toArray()
```